# Cropping Two Images to the Same Size

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have two pictures and would like to crop the width of the second to the same size as the width of the first using VBA. The problem I am facing is that it crops it such that they are almost, but not quite the same size (perhaps it only can crop by integers?).

```
Sub CropPicture()

Dim W1 As Double

Dim W2 As Double 

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

w1 = .width

End With

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)

W2 = .width

With .PictureFormat

.CropLeft = (W2 - W1)/2

.CropRight = (W2 - W1)/2

End With

End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I am a VBA novice

Comment: `CropLeft` and `CropRight` are applied to the original size of the picture, according to the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pictureformat-cropright-property-excel). Is there any scaling to your pic?

Comment: Hey Vincent - thanks for the reply. Yes there was scaling to the picture, perhaps I need to reset the scale before cropping.

Comment: Yes, reset the scale to 1 before measuring the width W2, and it should work.

Comment: Improved formating

Comment: I've now included a section that finds the original width and then comes up with a percentage to crop which goes, With ShapeToCrop.Duplicate.ScaleWidth 1,True  OrigWidth = .width  .delete End With          Which seems to work. Thanks!